# APP Crashes because of Large Bitmaps

Tags: android, bitmap

My problem is that my APP crashes because of the large Bitmaps. But I can't understand why. I was using my method (which you can see down below) and everything was fine even if it's not the best. But when I decided to add couple more imageViews then APP crashes. (Only on large dimensions images)
Any suggestions will help me.

```
ImageView im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimage);
        im.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        BitmapDrawable abmp = (BitmapDrawable) im.getDrawable();
        ImageView im1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.vienas);
        im1.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        BitmapDrawable abmp1 = (BitmapDrawable) im1.getDrawable();
        ImageView im2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.du);
        im2.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        BitmapDrawable abmp2 = (BitmapDrawable) im2.getDrawable();
        bmp = abmp.getBitmap();
        bmp = abmp1.getBitmap();
        bmp= abmp2.getBitmap();

        if (picturePath != null && bmp != null) {
            int height = bmp.getHeight(), width = bmp.getWidth();

            **if (height > 1280 && width > 960) {
                Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,(int)(bmp.getWidth()*0.8), (int)(bmp.getHeight()*0.8), true);
                bmp = resized;
                im.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                im.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                im1.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                im1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                im2.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                im2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);**

            } else {

                im.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                im.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                im1.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                im1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                im2.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                im2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

        }
```

Logcat:
Process: com.example.g.eternalstudios, PID: 30483
                                                                              java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 30483652 byte allocation with 16776176 free bytes and 25MB until OOM
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
                                                                                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:882)
                                                                                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:858)
                                                                                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:478)
                                                                                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:516)
                                                                                  at com.example.g.eternalstudios.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:208)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7137)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4921)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4968)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:222)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1849)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
    enter code here
    enter code here

Comment: did you try libraries like `Picasso` ?

Comment: Use libraries either 'Glide' or 'Picasso' to set image into ImageView it will help you.

Comment: use Glide or Picasso to set the images. These libraries helps in fast loading of images.

Comment: Please show the logcat. With the exception. NullPointerException?

Comment: @greenapps It says that it's OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: Well catch it to begin with. So your app does not have to crash. You try to create too much or too big bitmaps. Please tell the resolution of those images.

Comment: `bmp = abmp.getBitmap();
        bmp = abmp1.getBitmap();
        bmp= abmp2.getBitmap();` ???? What sense does this make?

Comment: @greenapps No sense. It's already deleted:) problem is not here..

Comment: It makes no sense to create bitmap drawable from imagevieuw. And then try to scale the bitmap who is thoo big. You should scale the bitmap while loading with decodeFile so the bitmap will always be small. Google for justDecodeBounds examples.